# Using for loops to calculate the certificate of deposit

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

For a highschool project I created a for loop that displays the 5 songs I initialised. I put it under the a button called btnInitializeActionPerformed so when the initialized button is pressed, it displays the songs, however it only displays the last song, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the loop

```
Collections.addAll (strSongArtist, "Dont Stop Believing", "this", "hello",  "Think", "No");

for (int i = 0; i < strSongArtist.size(); i++) {
       String valueContent = strSongArtist.get(i);
       txtOutput.setText( valueContent);
}
```

when I display strSongArtist like this in side the for loop:

```
System.out.println(strSongArtist.get(i));
```

Btw my teacher gave an example of outputing the code like this:

```
txtOutput.setText( strSongArtist.get(rn.nextInt(strSongArtist.size())).toString());
```

but I  have no idea how to use this either?

Comment: What is txtOutput? A JTextField? A JTextArea? You're replacing any String in that text component with the next String, so only the last shows. If a JTextArea, you want to use append not setText.

Comment: `txtOutput.setText( valueContent);` will replace the text instead of appending. One simple (yet not optimal or well designed) solution to this would be `txtOutput.setText( txtOutput.getText() + ", " + valueContent);`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the loop runs it is setting the text of `txtOutput` to the value of the `valueContent`, so it will display the last artist at the end of the loop. You should at least create a string and append each artist to it and set the text at the end of the loop

```
String artists = "";
for (int i = 0; i < strSongArtist.size(); i++) {
       artists += strSongArtist.get(i) + ", ";
}
 txtOutput.setText( artists );
```

Comment: You might want to add `", "` before the song and only if `i > 1` to prevent a trailing comma in the final text. Also note that it might be wise to use a `StringBuilder` here.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me!

Comment: Please mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling txtOutout.setText() during each loop iteration.

So, even if textOutput is some label/panel whatsoever that would be able to display more than string ... what you are doing is that you are telling it to **only** display that one string that you are passing to it.

Meaning: you have a loop that produces 5 individual strings. If you want those 5 strings to show up together, you have to build something that contains all those 5 individual strings.

You can either do that by collecting the results of your "get(i)" calls using a StringBuffer; or you call setTest() with the result of "getText() + "\n" + get(i)" ...